# ¿Me pueden quitar la sanción de no responder?

Tags: soporte, bloqueo-de-publicación

Hace mucho tiempo yo creé esta cuenta, empecé a responder algunas preguntas, a una de mis respuesta tenia una imagen que contenía el código de la solución... pero a alguien le dio el "no me gusta" por hacer eso.

Pero yo lo hacía por que si ponía mi código no podia comentar porque me salía el mensaje que mi comentario tenia código y como lo hacía desde la web y en mi celular no podia hacer eso.

Por otro lado después de ese dislike la plataforma no me dejó respoder a alguna de las preguntas, después de varia veces no aburrí y lo dejé y seguí con mi vida.

Y ahora que ha pasado el tiempo quiero dar ayudar, y responder alguna de las preguntas.

¿Me pueden quitar la sanción por favor?

Comment: no puedo comentar en esa plataforma... dice que nesesito almenos 5 puntos

Comment: pero nisiquiera puedo exponer mi caso..

Comment: gracias.. :)...

Comment: Ten paciencia. Si ya @Aprendiz reportó la pregunta a los moderadores ellos te ayudarán. Pero es importante que aprendas el motivo del bloqueo en el pasado y que si ahora quieres colaborar lo hagas observando los criterios del sitio. Las preguntas-respuestas basadas en código aportado en una captura de pantalla por ejemplo son poco viables, porque habría que re-escribir todo el código para implementarlo. Las respuestas que aportes deberían tener un mínimo de calidad, explicando las cosas y mostrando el texto del código. Si recibes votos en contra significa que debes mejorar la respuesta.

Comment: ok, lo voy a tomar en cuenta..

Comment: ya voy a editar ese comentario... como tu dices.

Comment: si, tienes razon estubo algo mal, en ese momebto era algo imaduro.. ya edite el comentario, ahora ya puede der entendido mas clara mente... tambien tuvo que ver que soy algo malo para explicar mas cosas.. :(

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Fue mucha confusión el votar en la cola de cierre en esta pregunta. Decidí votar por dejarla abierta, ¿Una pregunta personal puede ser duplicada de un caso general? Pensando por un rato pensé que no sería duplicada ya que es un caso personal. Además que la pregunta no se parece mucho. ¿Fue correcto el voto?

Comment: @ArtEze yo voté para cerrar por entender que el objetivo final de esta persona es conseguir volver a publicar, de allí que creo que la otra pregunta soluciona su problema.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Entiendo, si te parece bien puedo votar por el cierre fuera de la cola de revisiones.

Comment: @ArtEze como veas, no hay problema. También entiendo que votaras por dejar abierto. Veamos qué opina la comunidad en su conjunto

Answer (score 7):

He estado mirando tu cuenta y es un bloqueo automático (lo que quiere decir que los moderadores no podemos quitarlo). Este tipo de bloqueos los hace el sistema cuando las publicaciones del usuario no se ajustan bien a un algoritmo que desconozco, pero que en general parece centrarse en:

- Publicaciones con puntuaciones negativas.
- Publicaciones eliminadas (por el usuario o los moderadores).
- Reportes a publicaciones.

En tu caso, parecería que el problema es que tienes todas tus publicaciones están a 0 y tienes varias publicaciones eliminadas (ya sea por ti mismo o por los moderadores). No me termina de quedar claro por qué.

¿Qué puedes hacer para que se desbloquee tu cuenta para responder?

- Recupera tus preguntas eliminadas (si aplica, a veces no se puede).
- Mejora las respuestas que ya tienes (para recibir votos positivos).
- Escribe alguna pregunta que haga que suba tu reputación.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda. Viendo tus números, diría que estás en el borde. Seguramente con poco que hagas tu cuenta se desbloqueará y podrás volver a escribir respuestas muy pronto.

Edición: acabo de revisar tu perfil justo después de escribir esta respuesta, **alguien te dio un positivo en una respuesta que editaste hace unas horas y el bloqueo ha desaparecido**. Efectivamente, estabas al borde. Buena suerte en el sitio, esperamos ver tus respuestas :)

Aparte de eso: completa el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender más sobre el funcionamiento general del sitio y con ello ganar tu primera medalla.

Comment: Igual se que no debería decirlo, pero con base en las observaciones que le hice su aporte mejoro de calidad notablemente lo cual me llevo a darle el +1 considerando que su contenido sin duda será útil para muchos en la comunidad

Comment: gracias, una vez me paso que cuando iba dar la respuesta me equivoque de pregunta y pedi que la borran ya que la app que uso no lo permite.. estare aqui ayudando en lo que pueda... gracias a todos.